# Numpy: Quickly count True instances item-wise in 2D bool array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D boolean array, e.g.:

```
[[False, True, True],
[True, False, True],
[True, False, False],
[True, True, True]]
```

For each row in the array, I want to count the instances of True, and create a new item-wise array of the same shape as the original array in which each entry is the sum of all previous True instances in the row. For the above example, my desired output would be:

```
[[0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 2]]
```

Is there a way to do this quickly in Numpy rather than checking each item in the array like so:

```
boolarr = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]], dtype=np.bool)

newarr = np.zeros(boolarr.shape)

for i, row in enumerate(boolarr):
    for index, item in enumerate(row):
        if item:
            newarr[i][index+1:] += 1
```

My arrays are large enough (40 x 1260) and speed is a factor as this needs to be done repetitively a great number of times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cumsum` is your friend!  It's short for cumulative sum and you can give it an "axis" to work on, in your case try running:

```
np.cumsum(boolarr,axis=1) - boolarr
```

the subtraction just takes off the "current" value.

Comment: Simple, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use [`ndarray.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.cumsum.html) along the second axis and prepend with all zeros column at the start. Thus, assuming `A` as the input array, you could do  -

```
np.column_stack((np.zeros((A.shape[0],1),dtype=A.dtype),A[:,:-1].cumsum(1)))
```

A bit more efficient technique would be to initialize an output array with all zeros and then insert *cumsumm-ed* values into it, like so -

```
out = np.zeros(A.shape,dtype=int)
out[:,1:] = A[:,:-1].cumsum(1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [30]: A
Out[30]: 
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [31]: np.column_stack((np.zeros((A.shape[0]),dtype=A.dtype),A[:,:-1].cumsum(1)))
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]])

In [32]: out = np.zeros(A.shape,dtype=int)
    ...: out[:,1:] = A[:,:-1].cumsum(1)
    ...: 

In [33]: out
Out[33]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```